# hide keyboard of detailviewcontroller from rootviewcontroller

Tags: keyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a spliviewcontroller based ipad application. When the tableviewcell is selected from rootviewcontroller of splitview, its details are shown in detailviewcontroller of split view. In detailviewcontroller I have 2 textfields and 1 textview. Now when I type in any of these control, the keyboard comes up. If I tap outside the control (i.e inside detailview) the keyboard dismisses (which is correct). 
But if i tap on next tablecell , the kayboard does not get dismissed. 
What I want is , dismiss the keyboard when i tap on tablecell which is in rootviewcontroller. 
Can anyone plz help me in this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer of my own. 
In detailviewcontroller,method name:

```
-(void) configureView
{

  if ([txtTitleView isEditing]) //txtTitle is UITextField
  {
    flag = 1;
    [txtTitleView resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else if([txtTimeUnit isEditing]) //txtTimeUnit is UITextField
  {
    flag = 1;
    [txtTimeUnit resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else if(isTextViewEditing) //isTextViewEditing is a boolean variable
  {
    flag = 1;
    [txtSummaryView resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else
    flag = 0;
  }
```

this way the keyboard gets dismissed, and the delegate methods of textfield or textview gets called.